# DAX code to countrows when comparing values in two columns

Tags: compare, dax, measure

How can I compare values in two related tables to do a count in a measure?

Here is the measure formula I wrote - which does not work:

PoliciesPurchasedAsStudent = 
CALCULATE(Countrows(Policies),People[Date Graduated]>=Policies[Date Purchased]))

The People table contains one record per customer (including a column for Date Graduated)
The Policies table contains all the policies owned by all the customers (including a column for Date Purchased)
The tables are linked on the Customer ID number.

I just want to know how many policies were purchased by customers before they graduated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `RELATED()` function which lets you get the related value in `Policies` table.

```
PoliciesPurchasedAsStudent =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( Policies ),
    FILTER (
        People,
        People[Date Graduated] >= RELATED ( Policies[Date Purchased] )
    )
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Kerry, you are welcome, if my answer solved your issue you can mark it as the correct answer to inform other your problem was resolved. [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).